# How to parse / read JSON data into a Android ListView

Tags: android, json

I can't understand how to parse or read the JSON data, Pls Help me..

Here is structure of my JSON

```
{
      MENU: [
             {
               channel: "header",
               backgroundColor: "#e6e6e6"
             },
             {
               channel: "ad",
               title: "titel",
               icon: "image.png"                  
               link: "some_url"
             },
             {
               channel: "videos",
               title: "Videos",
               icon: "",
               feed: "some_url"
             },
             {
               channel: "header",
               background: "#e6e6e6"
             }
          ]
    }
```

Comment: Hey guys, thank for ur quick response. I got ans.

Comment: Don't forget to mark which ever answer best answered your question.

Comment: Just google your question and get more than 200+ relevant links... What a lazy guy ! You don't deserve answer

Answer (score 2):

The basics are

1. Turn string into JSON(Object/Array) `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(yourString);`
2. Create a ArrayAdapter to give you ListView
3. Follow this tutorial to create a ArrayAdapter [See here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html/)

If you'd have posted something more, like maybe anything you've tried I could help more, but that's the best answer you'll probably get for a vague question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I will suggest you to go through this [JSON](http://json.org/).Then check your response with [This site](http://jsonlint.com/).If this is valid `JSON` then you can move ahead for parsing logic.But here your response is not valid `JSON`.